# I am trying to parse cricket score from a site. Ans also want to be alerted if the score changes. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, automation, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I parsed the cricket score of a team. And stored it in a text file. Finally, I want to compare it to the web content that I have parsed. But nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

url = "http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/15788/ind-vs-pak-19th-match-super-10-group-2-icc-world-t20-2016"

def hello():
fine = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(fine, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "cb-min-bat-rw"}):
    result1 = re.sub(r'<.*?>', "", str(link))
    print(result1)
    while True:
        simp = open('te.txt', 'w')
        simp.write(result1)
        simp.close()
        samp = open('te.txt', 'r')
        love = samp.read()
        samp.close()
        if love == result1:
            print("value not changed")
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            print(result1)
            break
hello()
```

This is my output (It doesn't detect the score changes. It keeps saying value not changed):

```
C:\Users\vasanth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/vasanth/PycharmProjects/Youtube/hell.py
IND 9/0 (1.3 Ovs)  CRR: 6  REQ: 6.67
value not changed
value not changed
value not changed
value not changed
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *`urllib` is not a browser* - it would not receive the score updates live. You need to resend the request to the same page to see the updated score, reparse the HTML source code with `BeautifulSoup` again, locate the element corresponding to the current score.

Or, you can approach it in an entirely different way - open the page with a real browser automated by [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and periodically find the current score element.